# Ormlite 5.0 Master-detail relationship

Tags: android, ormlite

I need your help for decide next throuble.
I have two class Order and OrderProduct, in the Order class has property of collection OrderProduct which return empty. I don't understand what problem, because I set eager = true. you can see my code below.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName=Order.TABLE_NAME)
public class Order extends Document {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "order";

    @DatabaseField( generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private ForeignCollection<OrderProduct> products;

    private IPrepareOrder iPrepareOrder;

    public  Order(){

    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Collection<OrderProduct> getProducts(){
        return products;
    }   
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName=OrderProduct.TABLE_NAME)
public class OrderProduct {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "orderProduct";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Order order;

    @DatabaseField(foreignColumnName = "id", canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Product product;

    public OrderProduct(){

    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public Order getOrder(){
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order){
        this.order = order;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe I use to incorrect code when trying add entry to details?

Comment: I got almost same trouble, and I'd like to know. Do you decide it?